# http://localhost:8080/test/ is working but http://localhost:8080/ is giving 404 error

Tags: eclipse, localhost, tomcat6

I am running a web application in eclipse.
It is working fine.

But when I delete the test/ then->following error is display.

```
type Status report

message /

description The requested resource is not available.
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a index.php file. When you access a server, the server looks for a file called `index` that can redirect the user to the homepage. See [here](http://docs.joomla.org/index.php?title=What_is_the_purpose_of_the_index.php_file?) for more information.

This is what I **think** you are asking. Your question was not easy to understand.